# any CURL setting to append a domain suffix to a shortname when doing dns loookup

Tags: curl, dns

I'm having an issue with my curl usage on dns lookup for shortname.

The scenario is: when connecting to a server via shortname (full url is xxx.domainA.com, but I give curl just xxx, then curl only tries to lookup xxx w/o any suffix which of course results in a failure from dns server - I observed these packets via wireshark. I'm expecting curl will add the suffix with the domain of the machine that is running my curl app. But I guess this would not automatically happen. So my question is: did I miss any seeting to curl(any curl_easy_setopt, curl_multi_setopt or even curl_share_setopt)?

As a side note: 
1. I'm on Win7
2. if using the full url xxx.domainA.com in my app, it works like a charm.
3. curl tool command line works fine with shortname "curl xxx" or full url "curl xxx.domainA.com"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `curl` is pulling from the correct server via ns resolution but the `request url` is based on the shortname. The `http server` should be configured to return 302 with the fully qualified name. Http code 302 is a redirection.